# I can't take the value attribute on button | jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made ajax script for delete button and have data attribute based on id on the table in database. This is the HTML :

```
<textarea name="komentar" id="komentar" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    <br><br><hr><br>
    <!-- Komentar akan ada di dalam sini -->
    <div id="komentar_wrapper">

        <?php 
        include_once 'db.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM komentar ORDER BY id DESC";
        $show_comments = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        foreach ($show_comments as $comment) { ?>
            <p id="komentar_<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>"><?php echo $comment['komentar']; ?>
            <!-- data-id-> data attribute, buat spesifik id mana yang mau di hapus -->
                <button id="button_hapus" class="hapus_komentar" data-id="<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>">Delete</button> 
            </p>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

And when i try to console the data-id, it wont show the value on console. This is the script :

```
$(".hapus_komentar").on("click", function() {

        console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));

});
```

When i click the button it say undefined, i think it should print the id based on button data-id

Answer (score 2):

**try this i have prepared a demo code for you and runs ok**

```
<?php

        $as = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
        foreach ($as as $comment) { ?>
            <p id="komentar_<?php echo $comment ?>"><?php echo $comment; ?>

                <button id="button_hapus" class="hapus_komentar" data-id="<?php echo $comment; ?>">Delete</button> 
            </p>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(".hapus_komentar").on("click", function() {
            alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
            //console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Jquery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/). and use event delegation since your button is generated dynamically.

```
$(document).on("click",".hapus_komentar",function() {

        console.log($(this).data("id"));

});
```

You can use `$(this).data("id")` to get the id.

Comment: welcome @BudiHaryono . please accept the answer. if it helped you. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Just check in HTML weather data-id will have value or not. Maybe that's the reason you are not getting proper value. As well you have taken that button in the loop so make sure on individual button click you will get all buttons data-id.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".hapus_komentar").on("click", function() {

        console.log($(this).data("id"));

});
```

now use this.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on("click",".hapus_komentar",function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
  });
```

Comment: code-only answers aren't useful for the community. Please explain why your snippet solves the problem. Please look at [answer]

Comment: I will take care next time